# Firebase (Firestore) custom authentication with SSO controlled by a third party

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, jwt

I am building a Firebase application (using Firestore) which needs to support custom authentication via single sign on through a third party system.

In the past, I have done this type of integration with my own authentication system.  To do this, I installed the Firebase Admin SDK on my own server and used the secret key to sign a JWT that was passed back to the client, which then could be used to grant access to the Firebase application.

However, since the Admin SDK grants full access to the Firebase app, I have concerns about handing those keys over to another party.  Is there a way that I can provide a secret key that grants more limited privileges to the third party?  I want them to be able mint JWTs for their users to access the app, but I don't want them to be able to directly read/write from my database.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved this by taking the following steps... 

1) Access the Firebase project's IAM admin tools
2) Create a new service account for the project in the "Service Accounts" section.
3) Create a custom role in the "Roles" section and give it access to all of the Firebase Authentication privileges: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions#auth
4) Assign the custom role to the service account in the "IAM" section of the admin interface.
5) Go back to the "Service Accounts" section and create/download a private key for this service account.
6) Use this key as the credentials for the Firebase Admin SDK and create a custom token using the process detailed here: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

The SDK should permit creating a custom token, but it will return errors when trying to do other actions such as accessing the project's database.